# How to set a first draft date and a current draft date?

Tags: datetime

I want to insert two dates into my article class TeX file:  first draft date and current draft date, how can I achieve that?

In most examples that I see in pdf form, it centers on the page the following:

```
First Draft: Date
Current Draft: Date
```

Comment: How do you define "draft"? Last time it was saved? Compiled?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest hard-coding the never-changing "first draft" date and using `\today` for the "current draft":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/isodate
\begin{document}
First draft: \printdate{1.1.2013} \par
Current draft: \today
\end{document}
```

Different date formatting options are available. See the [`isodate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/isodate) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/isodate/isodate.pdf) for more information.